# Open graphical Windows applications without monitor and control it

Tags: windows, automation, headless

I have an Windows server with multiple applications installed on it. For each application we created a macro that interects over it. For example, open the ERP -> go to product registration -> add a new product. Thoses scritps are working, but only if windows has an active display. How can I simulate a virtual display on Windows, so the macros can still work.

Answer (score 0):

Up until Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, there used to be a flag "Interact with desktop" when running services / scheduled tasks. This flag has been removed in more recent Windows versions but can still be activated through a legacy option controlled by the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\NoInteractiveServices
```

Set its value to 0 to allow services to interact with the desktop.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/interactive-services for more information on how to execute interactive services.